# Multiple optional filters in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am very new to `angular` and, I am not sure how to control the behavior of my filters.

In the app, I have two different `single-select` drop down controls that filter the results of my data set and fill a table. However, even though these filters work, the results are dependent of both controls and if both are not being used , the empty set is returned. So, my question is: How can I use these filters optionally? So, the app returns **every** result when the filters are not used or returns the filtered results by one of the controls or both?

Thank you

Here is the code:

**AngularJS**

The filters for each control. They look very similar:

```
.filter('byField', function () {
    return function (results, options) {
        var items = { options: options, out: [] };
        angular.forEach(results, function (value, key) {

            for (var i in this.options) {
                if ((options[i].value === value.fieldId && 
                     options[i].name === "Field" && 
                     options[i].ticked === true)) {
                        this.out.push(value);
                     }
            }
        }, items);
        return items.out;
    };
})

.filter('byClass', function () {
    return function (results, options) {
        var items = { options: options, out: [] };
        angular.forEach(results, function (value, key) {

            for (var i in this.options) {
                if ((options[i].value === value.documentClass &&
                     options[i].name === "Class" && 
                     options[i].ticked === true)) {
                        this.out.push(value);
                     }
            }

        }, items);
        return items.out;
    };
})
```

**HTML**

This is what I am doing to populate the `rows` of the table:

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in results | byField:outputFields | byClass:outputClasses">
    <td>{{result.documentId}}</td>
    ...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I imagined the answer was more related to `set theory` than to `angular`.

I just made an `union` between the empty set and every result, and it worked.

```
.filter('byField', function () {
    return function (results, options) {
        var items = { options: options, out: [] };
        angular.forEach(results, function (value, key) {
            if (options.length) {
                for (var i in this.options) {
                    if ((options[i].value === value.fieldId &&
                         options[i].name === "Field" && 
                         options[i].ticked === true)) {
                            this.out.push(value);
                         }
                }
            } else {
                this.out = results.slice();                        
            }                   
        }, items);
        return items.out;
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Dorado7.1 in all event listeners provides a view implicit variable pointing to the current event host's view, the variable can completely replace the use of this scenario.